# How to number data attribute dynamically for elements jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I want to add to img new attribute `data-index` with its listing number dynamically.
So I tried something like this, but it's not correct:

```
var $slides = $(".slide-img img");
for( var i = 0; i < $slides.length; i++ ){
    $slides.attr("data-index", i);
};
```

Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. You just need `[i]` so it looks like `$($slides[i])`

```
var $slides = $(".slide-img img");
for( var i = 0; i < $slides.length; i++ ){
    $($slides[i]).attr("data-index", i);
};
```

Problem: `$slides.attr("data-index", i);` would set the highest value of `i` onto all of the `$slides`

**Demo**

```js
var $slides = $(".slide-img img");
for( var i = 0; i < $slides.length; i++ ){
    $($slides[i]).attr("data-index", i);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt=""> alt
</div>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt=""> alt
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a pure JQuery solution:

```js
$(".slide-img img").each(function(i){
    $(this).data("index", i);
});
    
//validation script - print all index in the closest <span>
$(".slide-img img").each(function(){$(this).siblings().text($(this).data("index"))});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="slide-img">
    <img src="img/bg2.jpg" alt="">
    <span></span>
</div>
```